# How to integrate find command with mv command?

Tags: find, mv

I was trying to move all files whose names begin with uppercase letters from the current directory to a directory called `u` under `~/tmp`.

I tried this command: `find . -type f -name "*[[upper]]*" -exec mv -t ~/tmp/u`
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You’re very close.

1. You need colons in the `[[:upper:]]` token.
2. `"*[[:upper:]]*"` will find every name
   that *contains* an upper-case letter. 
   To get only the files whose names *begin* with uppercase letters,
   use `"[[:upper:]]*"` (leave off the first `*`).
3. If you say just

   ```
   find . -name '[[:upper:]]*'
   ```

   it will *list* all the files whose names begin with uppercase letters. 
   But, when you use `-exec`,
   you have to tell `find` to include the filename in the command, using `{}`.

   (And you should *always* debug `find` commands
   in a print-only mode before you try to tell it to run commands,
   especially commands that modify the file system. 
   Using `-exec echo mv …`
   is a common debugging technique.)
4. But, when you use `-exec`, you have to end the command with `';'`
   (or, equivalently, `\;`) or `+`. 
   (See the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html),
   or [Stéphane Chazelas's answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665535/80216#665537), for the difference.) 
   Since you are using `mv -t`, you can use `+`.

So your final command is

```
find . -name '[[:upper:]]*' -exec mv -t ~/tmp/u {} +
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works with: find . -name '[A-Z]*' -exec mv -t ~/tmp/u {} +

Comment: @NatnaelMekonnenTsehay If the answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Comment: @AdminBee: Thanks for the plug, but this is the only question Natnael Mekonnen Tsehay has posted, not just on U&L, but on all of Stack Exchange, and he hasn’t logged in for six months, so he probably isn’t going to see your comment. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S.  I see that you’re on track to hit 20K before your three-year anniversary!   Good job!   It took me eight years to get this far.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Ah, you are right, I hadn't checked that. And thanks - let's see if it works out, I recently had somewhat less time to be active around here ... :)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax, with the GNU implementation of `mv` is:

```
find . -type f -name '[[:upper:]]*' -exec mv -t ~/tmp/u {} +
```

Or standardly:

```
find . -type f -name '[[:upper:]]*' -exec sh -c '
   exec mv "$@" ~/tmp/u/' sh {} +
```

That is for the pattern to match on a file name that *starts* with an uppercase letter, you want it to match on an uppercase letter (the `[:upper:]` POSIX character class inside a `[...]` bracket expression) followed by any number of characters (`*`).

You must tell `find` where the `-exec some command with its args` ends. That's either with:

- a `;` argument (which in a shell command line you must quote with for instance `';'`, `\;`, `";"`... as `;` is also a special character in all shells) which tells `find` to execute the command once for each file (and in that case each occurrence of `{}` in the command line arguments is replaced with the path of the file).
- or the sequence of `{}` `+` arguments. There can only be one `{}` and it must be before the `+`. In that case the command is called for several files at a time, and `{}` is replaced with the list of files.

So `find` ends up running:

- `mv -t /home/you/tmp/u ./File1 ./File2 ./dir/File3...` in the first case, where `-t` allows all the source files to be at the end.
- `sh -c 'mv "$@" ~/tmp/u/' sh ./File1 ./File2 ./dir/File3...` POSIXly. Without `-t`, we need to call `sh` to reorder the arguments so `~/tmp/u/` can be at the end. Here, `sh` eventually runs: `mv ./File1 ./File2 ./dir/File3... /home/you/tmp/u/` (in the same process because of `exec`; some `sh` implementations do that optimisation already without the need for an explicit `exec`).

The trailing `/` in `mv ... ~/tmp/u/` is to make sure `mv` enters the *move-into* mode. `mv a b` either renames `a` to `b` (*move-to*) or to `b/a` (*move-into*) depending on whether `b` is a directory or not. By adding the trailing `/`, we make sure it's the latter, or at least that if `b` is not a directory, an error is reported instead of renaming `a` to `b` (doing a *move-to*). In the `find` code above, that's to cover for the case where `find` finds only one file. `mv a b c` (to move more than one file) is always a *move-into* operation (which requires `c` to be a directory), as *move-to* would not make sense in that case.

Comment: You might want to mention that the trailing slash isn’t needed in the ```mv -t``` command because the ```-t``` implies “*move-into*” mode.

Comment: Thank You. Your suggestions are also worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
find . -type f -name "[A-Z]*" -exec mv  {} <destination directory> \;
```